# Sort array values by their existence in a blacklist array, then alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, blacklist, custom-sort

I have the following code:

```
$check = array('person a','person c');
$data = array('person c','person a','person d','person e');
define('check',$check);
//asort($data);

print'<pre>';print_r($data);print'</pre>';

usort($data,function($a,$b){
    return empty(check[$a]) ? 1 : $a <=> $b;
});

print'<pre>';print_r($data);print'</pre>';
exit;
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
person d
person e
person a
person c
```

What I get is

```
person e
person a
person d
person c
```

Because person a and c are in the `$check` array, I'm trying to sort my array based on alphabetically for those not in the $check group and then those who are. I could probably split things up a bit and am not overly familiar with the `usort` custom functions, but is it possible to acheive it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "mapping" array using [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to flag each `$data` item, then [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/array_multisort) both the mapping array and the `$data` array:

```
<?php

$check = array('person a','person c');
$data = array('person c','person a','person d','person e');

function dmap ($itm) {
    GLOBAL $check;
    return ((int)in_array($itm, $check)+1) . $itm;
}

$mm = array_map('dmap', $data);
array_multisort($mm, $data);
print_r($data);

exit;
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => person d
    [1] => person e
    [2] => person a
    [3] => person c
)
```

When providing two arrays to `array_multisort()` the function sorts the first array, ascending by default, and applies the sorted order of the first array to the second.

The "mapping" array simply prepends a `1` or `2` to each element of the `$data` array to affect the sort order moving the items not found in the `$check` into first sort position.

Try it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/5ae10

Comment: Thanks. And for anyone working it through - the `array_multisort` sorts the resulting `$mm` by SORT_ASC first which is appears to be the PHP default. This order is then applied to the $data array.

Comment: I see, I didn't describe that very well. I updated my explanation—thanks.

Comment: No problem - and I hope my comment didn't come across rude! It was certainly not meant to :o)

Answer (score 1):

The most modern approach is to use `array_map()` with arrow syntax and check if each data value is in the check array.  When sorting booleans ascending, false comes before true.

`array_multisort()` is a better choice versus `usort()` in this case because fewer `in_array()` call will be made.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y8oZE))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => in_array($v, $check), $data),
    $data
);
var_export($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Firstly get all the items in the first array which aren't in the second array:

```
$data = array_diff($data, $check);
```

Sort both arrays:

```
usort($data,function($a,$b){
    return $a <=> $b;
});

usort($check,function($a,$b){
    return $a <=> $b;
});
```

Merge them together

```
$merged = array_merge($data, $check);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this assumes all people in `$check` are to be included - hence my `empty(check[$a])` but it does produce the desired data set.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by 2 criteria:

1. if the element exists in $last it should go to the end
2. then alphabetically

This can be done with usort alone. Some entries were added to the data to make the test more reliable.

```
$data = array('person f','person c','person g','person a','person d','person e');

$last = array('person a','person c','person g');

usort($data,function($a,$b) use($last){
  return in_array($a,$last) <=> in_array($b,$last)  //sort if in $last
  ?: $a <=> $b;  //sort alphabetically
});

var_export($data);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/B3G8s